# SQL Server: Change Tracking can ignore the field that is changed with the same value?

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

I am tracking specific columns changes in table  (example :tracking CustomerName, Address1 in  TestCustomer Table), using Change Tracking functions in SQL Server. Everything looks good  so far with the code underneath , however noticed when I update the field with the same value like customerName=customerName as below  :

```
update TestCustomers set customerName=customerName where CustomerID= 2
```

so the query will still show me there is a change on this customerName. The question is: using Change Tracking functions, is there a field or way can show me this field's content is not really changed? and still has the same content ?
below is the full sql script and the result :

```
create table dbo.TestCustomers
( 
CustomerID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
customerName varchar(255) not null,
 Address1 varchar(255) null,

 CONSTRAINT [PK__TestCustomers__customerid] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( CustomerID ASC )
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
insert into  TestCustomers (CustomerName,Address1)
values ('custName1','custaddress1')
insert into  TestCustomers (CustomerName,Address1)
values ('custName2','custaddress2')
insert into  TestCustomers (CustomerName,Address1)
values ('custName3','custaddress3')
insert into  TestCustomers (CustomerName,Address1)
values ('custName4','custaddress4')

ALTER TABLE TestCustomers 
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING  
WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)  
select CustomerID,customerName,address1 from TestCustomers  where CustomerID=2
update TestCustomers set customerName=customerName where CustomerID= 2
select CustomerID,customerName,address1 from TestCustomers where CustomerID=2
SELECT
ChVer = SYS_CHANGE_VERSION,
ChCrVer = SYS_CHANGE_CREATION_VERSION,
ChOp = SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION,
CustomerName_Changed = CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK
    (COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('TestCustomers'), 'CustomerName', 'ColumnId')
    ,ChTbl.sys_change_columns),
Address1_Changed = CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK
    (COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('TestCustomers'), 'Address1', 'ColumnId')
    ,ChTbl.sys_change_columns),
CustomerID
FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES TestCustomers, 1) AS ChTbl;
```

[image: CustomerName is changed with the same value]

as you can see from the picture, in spite the customerName is changed with the same content, but the result is showing the as  changes, I am looking to see only record where the content is actually changed ! please help if there is way to distinguish if the content is changed or not, mainly through Change Track !
Please Note: We are not interested of knowing what was the the content, just need to know if content of this field is changed or not !
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  It would be extra work to figure out if an UPDATE is actually changing the data, and [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) is optimized for simplicity and low overhead.  If you want this information, or need to see all the intermediate versions of rows, then [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) might be a better choice.